# Library sources not found for scala-library in Intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I have an imported sbt project. During import I did NOT click on download sbt sources - and I am unclear as to whether that were the cause of the subsequent issue.  In any case is there a way to remedy the missing library as shown in the screenshot?

[image]

Clicking on "Download" results in the "Library sources aren't found" as seen above.

**Update** From an answer below: Going to Other settings|default settings|Build, Execution, Deployment|build tools|SBT   Here is what I see:

[image]

**Another update** I went to the Intellij Idea|Preferences|Execution,Deployment,Build and see the following

[image]

Note: even after checking **Download sbt docs and sources** it does not "take": it remains unchecked the next time the dialog is brought up.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`File` -> `Settings` -> `Build, Execution, Deployment` -> `Build Tools` -> `SBT`, check the "Download sources and Docs". open the SBT panel, and click refresh. Voila.

Comment: I do not see that option: am updating the OP

Comment: Can you expand the project-level settings or global sbt settings from there?

Comment: No, those are not links/buttons they are just labels.

Comment: OK, I think you are in macOS, I suppose in windows. I tried on mac and the path is here:
IntelliJ IDEA -> preference -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> SBT -> see project level settings.

Comment: Updated OP. For some reason the heckbox "Download SBT sources and docs" does not stay checked/enabled.

Comment: Try File -> Invalidate Cache/Restart ... to see if that can clean up a bit.

Comment: No, that does not do it. Actually that command is more for when there are spurious class files / libraries to be removed.

Answer (score 4):

I'm constantly fighting Intellij on Windows (across different versions and updates... mostly EAP, so it's probably my fault), but if I add `withSources() withJavadoc()` to the end of a library dependency:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.twitter" %% "finatra-http" % versions.finatra withSources() withJavadoc(),
```

it will download the source and docs.  Then when I click `Attach Sources...` if I point to that in my cache, Intellij will finally update and load the sources correctly.

See http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Management.html#Download+Sources for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Close the project.  Then File -> Open...  and select the actual build.sbt file in the "open project" dialog.  Opening it from the actual sbt file should show you a dialog that tells you it'll download source, docs, etc.

I used IntelliJ CE 2017.2.6